# IP bases access control list script

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos5, varnish

I would like to setup ACL (python script or any ready made Centos compatible scipt) & limit rate for all IP addresses, who are hitting the site very frequently. For example crawlers, bots (except google & bing bots).

After identifying the ip address, script should automatically add those IP address to IPTABLES so that they cannot access the site.

I have following application added to my Centos OS

1. Apache 2.x
2. MySQL 5.2
3. Varnish
4. Memcache
5. APC

I would like the script should satisfy our requirement i.e:

1. Block crawler/users other than google & bit who are hitting server too hard.
2. Don't block white listed ip address/ip regions.
3. Make sure it can be used for commercial purpose.
4. It doesn't impact performance further.

Please advise what is best possible solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be asking for [**`fail2ban`**](http://www.fail2ban.org/)

Comment: Thanks for providing the link. I have one doubt, will fail2ban block googlebot and bingbot too? I saw someone mentioned this in a forum http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/fail2ban-noscript-jail-is-banning-googlebot-should-i-make-an-exception-4175428839/